# Thermionic emission, delayed emission and predissociation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy, atomic-physics, molecules, molecular-dynamics

In molecular [photodissociation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodissociation), the [thermionic emission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_emission), [delayed emission](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=delayed+emission) and [predissociation](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=predissociation) are the same? Otherwise, what is the difference between them?

My question is not about the solids, but I am saying about molecules/clusters.

References:

1. J.U. Anderson et.al., J.Phys.B: At.Mol.Opt.Phys. 35 (2002) R1-R30.

Comment: Thermionic emission and delayed emission are normally properties of metals, or at least solids, and I can't see any relation to photodissociation of molecules. Can you make your question a bit clearer because it isn't obvious what you're asking.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Thermionic emission and delayed emission happens in clusters as well. My question is about the clusters.

Answer (score 1):

Thermionic emission is the emission of electrons from a certain solid (usually metals, due to free electrons - good conductivity) which are in a thermally induced state of excitement. This excitement causes the electrons to emitted from said material.